# How to get data from specific action on php page

Tags: php, html, jquery

i have tried some code to pass the data with jquery ajax to other php with specific action.

this my php code on service.php

```
if ($_POST["aksi"]=="actionA"){
$id_alam=$_POST['id_alamat'];
}
elseif ($_POST["aksi"]=="actionB"){

}
```

there is the html code and ajax request

```
<a id="4" href="#" class="hapus-alamat col-sm-3">Delete</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('.hapus-alamat').click(function(){
    
      var id_alamat=$(this).attr('id');
      $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            dataType:"json",
            url:"service.php",
            data:'aksi=actionA='+id_alamat,
            success: function(data) {
                          alert(data);
                    }
      });
      
   });

</script>
```

i tried some code and the php file cant get the variable until now

here my result...
how can i pass the url and $_POST together??
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPN2y.jpg)

Comment: `data:'aksi=actionA&id_alamat='+id_alamat,`

Comment: The `aksi` value is `actionA=4` in the example above. The conditions in your PHP do not handle that

Comment: Let me tryyy ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code instead of this `data:'aksi=actionA='+id_alamat,`

```
       data:{aksi:'actionA', id_alamat:id_alamat},
```

thanks